# Merging Two Dataframes on Different Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Merging two dataframes on two different columns and rename the other two columns.

```
 df1
 Male    height 
 Alex    156
 Philip  178

 df2
 Female  height
 Alex    144
 Janice  150
```

I want a dataframe like this

```
 df3
 Person   M_Height  F_Height
 Alex      156        144 
 Philip    178         0
 Janice     0         150
```

How do i achieve this? Merge gives me both columns separately if i say right on and left on.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [21]: pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Male':'Person'}),
                  df2.rename(columns={'Female':'Person'}),
    ...:          on='Person', how='outer', suffixes=['_M','_F']) \
    ...:   .fillna(0)
Out[21]:
   Person  height_M  height_F
0    Alex     156.0     144.0
1  Philip     178.0       0.0
2  Janice       0.0     150.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try this to fix your code (***Merge gives me both columns separately if i say right on and left on***)

```
df=df1.merge(df2,left_on='Male',right_on='Female',how='outer',suffixes=['_M','_L'])
df.assign(Person=(df[['Male','Female']].ffill(axis=1)).Female).drop(['Male','Female'],axis=1).fillna(0)

Out[890]: 
   height_M  height_L  Person
0     156.0     144.0    Alex
1     178.0       0.0  Philip
2       0.0     150.0  Janice
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to change the column names to be non-overlapping

```
df1.columns = ['M_Height']
df2.columns = ['F_Height']
```

The second step is to merge the dataframes.

```
df = pd.merge([df1, df2], how='outer')
```